# Possible to Create Group

Tags: view, grouping

Problem:
Is it possible to create a view with grouping or group for a library? In my case I heard about but not knowing if it possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in the create view options towards the bottom is a section for Grouping.  Here you can choose which column you would like to group by.